# Displaying a bitmap image in MFC dialog using C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, display, bmp

Here is my code:

```cpp
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
    CBitmap BmpLady;
    // Load the bitmap from the resource
    BmpLady.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);

    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CDC MemDCLady;

    // Create a memory device compatible with the above CPaintDC variable
    MemDCLady.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    // Select the new bitmap
    //CBitmap *BmpPrevious = MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
    MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
    // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, 426, 640, &MemDCLady, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> the application is running, but no image is displayed in dialog. I am new to MFC, so any help would be appreciated. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong in my code?
Thank you in advance.

Note: I am working in Visual Studio 2019

SlidingPuzzleNWP.rc:

```
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "res\\SlidingPuzzleNWP.ico"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Bitmap
//

IDR_MAINFRAME           BITMAP                  "res\\Toolbar.bmp"

IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "res\\slika_za_rad.bmp"

IDB_BITMAP2             BITMAP                  "res\\tito.bmp"
```

resource.h:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by SlidingPuzzleNWP.rc
//
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDR_SlidingPuzzleNWPTYPE        130
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     310
#define IDB_BITMAP2                     311

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        312
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           310
#endif
#endif
```

Childview.cpp:

```
// ChildView.cpp : implementation of the CChildView class
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "SlidingPuzzleNWP.h"
#include "ChildView.h"
#include "resource.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Comment: What does `LoadBitmap` return?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to display the return value of LoadBitmap because when i run the program only the mfc dialog is displayed, not a console.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable, and inspect its value in a [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/).

Comment: Ok, I used GetLastError() function just after LoadBitmap and the return value is 0.

Comment: `CBitmap::LoadBitmap` calls [LoadBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadbitmapw). Ancient GDI code, born before `GetLastError` had been invented. All error/success information you get here is the return value. It's a *"Yes/No"* thing, no newfangled inquiries like *"Why did you leave me!?"* allowed.

Comment: So are you saying that I shouldn't use GetLastError(), I'm confused? I am sorry if you find my questions 'stupid' but english is not my first language and I'm new to C++ and MFC.

Comment: No, you shouldn't call `GetLastError` here. This API doesn't set the last error code on failure. The only information about the success of invoking `CBitmap::LoadBitmap` is by inspecting its return value. There is no other information available in case it returns `FALSE`.

Comment: You can use `CBitmap::Draw` method which is passed a handle to a device context. Probably easier. I think you just pass it the `CPaintDC` handle. And, you might need the bitmap you be loaded at class level instead of local to the message handler.

Comment: @IInspectable is guiding you well. [`CBitmap::LoadBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbitmap-class?loadbitmap) returns a `BOOL` value, so you can do `BOOL res= BmpLady.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);` put a breakpoint there and see what is the value of `res` after the line has executed.

Comment: For painting "graphical" type views (`CView`, `CScrollView` and descendants) you normally use the `OnDraw()` event - it passes you a proper `CDC*` parameter for your painting. Btw what kind of class is `CChildView`? You may not call `OnDraw()` yourself, instead you should call `Invalidate()`, `InvalidateRect()`, or `RedrawWindow()` to trigger painting. Finally, what does the handler for the `F5` key do? You should invalidate the window in there (normally you have to fetch/update the data being displayed AND invalidate/paint the window).

Comment: Hi thank you all for your input.  CBitmap::LoadBitmap returns 0.

Comment: @IIinspectable `CBitmap::LoadBitmap` returns 0. @sergiol thanks:) @Andrew Truckle @ Constantine Georgiou I don't know what you mean currently, my profesor suggested this code ( I had to find it and use it from my script)

Comment: If `CBitmap::LoadBitmap` returns 0, then something went wrong, the problem is probably within your ressource file. Check if there is actually a `IDB_BITMAP1` bitmap ressource.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you. Yes, there is an `IDB_BITMAP1` in my resource file. I tried everything I know. Do you maybe have some idea what is wrong? I can send you the project or display the resource file here somehow.

Comment: In this project I am trying to make a Sliding Puzzle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle That's why I need a bitmap image to display in dialoge when I run the program.

Comment: There needs to be a resource [**of type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-types) `RT_BITMAP` with ID `IDB_BITMAP1` in your resource script. The resource script needs to be compiled and linked into the final executable image. And the bitmap needs to be a valid BMP file. Please verify that all of these are true.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you. I edited my questions to include the contents of the files. I think everything is ok. The image I used was converted from .jpeg to .bmp using online converter since I couldn't find .bmp picture online.

Comment: BMP's are complex files. Most software solutions that write BMP files get it wrong. If you need a proper BMP file, open whichever file you have generated into MS Paint, and just save it from there without  modifications. That will get you a valid BMP file.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes I did it just like you told me, but when i go to Resources->Add->new resource->Bitmap->Import I always get the same message: "Could not load file. Unknown bitmap resource." I just don't know what to do anymore:(

Comment: And every time I do that Visual Studio freezes and restarts

Comment: I remember I had to downgrade Gimp to an old.version, to get the.bitmaps it saved to be assimilable by MFC. Not sure what the version now, but I think it was 2.6 the versipn I downgraded to. I am on vacation and far from my work's computer now, I only can tell surely what the version when I will come back.

Comment: You do not need to re-import the bitmap resource into your Visual Studio project. Simply replace the old file with the new one, and recompile. Just keep in mind that you cannot trust **any** software to create valid BMPs, other than MS Paint. Not sure why that is the case, but if Adobe Photoshop gets it wrong, that is telling.